# Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook createSheet() return NullPointerException

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I`m using SXSSFWorkbook for streaming large amount of data (~990k of records) which should be written in a XLS file.
The problem with the following code is when it is deployed on linux server. On my local machine (win 10 x64) works as expected.
Version of Apache POI is 4.1.2.

```
Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(SXSSFWorkbook.DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet(); <-- NPE
```

Here is the log snippet

```
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:273)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.AutoSizeColumnTracker.<init>(AutoSizeColumnTracker.java:117)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.<init>(SXSSFSheet.java:82)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:684)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:676)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:88)
at com.odfl.altair.controller.MyController.selectAll(MyController.java:211)
```

As you can see on MyController at line 211 I have createSheet() method call. I`ve tried createSheet() and createSheet("SheetName").

Thank you

Comment: Do you have all the fonts installed on the linux box? Looks like it might be failing when trying to figure out how wide to make the columns based on the font in use

Comment: You're right. I've installed fonts and now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my alpaine-based docker container (there are no required fonts). Migration to ubuntu-based image fixed the problem.

for alpaine-based container you should add some fonts and libs to your Dockerfile. It worked for me with:

```
apk add curl bash wget fontconfig ttf-dejavu freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev libpng-dev
```

Comment: Helping future Google searches out here: That's Alpine Linux. I ran into the same issue in a Docker container. Solved by installing fontconfig and ttf-dejavu via "apk add".

Comment: Can you please elaborate about how to add this line in Dockerfile?